# macro excel with cycles

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a problem implementing operations with different files on excel2016.

Knowing that the "Source" folder contains 5 files named Car1, Car2, Car3, Car4,Car5

knowing that the "Destination" folder contains the excel file "Home", the macro I am trying to write should perform the following operations:

Copy the data in the range from E4 to E124 for each file in the "Source" folder and paste the first range into the second sheet of the "Home" workbook, the second range into the third sheet of the "Home" workbook, and so on...

I'm not able to write it correctly, additionally I alway get "runtime error 1004 method of range class failed"

Here's an example of the vba macro I tried:

```
  Dim wbSource As Workbook
  Dim wbDest As Workbook
  Dim wsDest As Worksheet
  Dim i  As Integer

Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open("C:\Destination\Home.xlsx")

for i =1 to 5
  Set wbSource= Workbooks.Open("C:\Source\Car" & i & ".xlsx")
  Set wsDest=wbDest.Sheets(i)
  wbSource.Sheets(1).Range("E4:E124").Copy wsDest.Range("A1")
  wbSource.Close
 Next i
wbDest.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Thank you so much if you could help me

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Data Using a Loop

- The `Sheets` collection also includes charts. Use the `Worksheets` collection instead.
- You said 1st range (source worksheet) to the 2nd destination worksheet hence use `i + 1`.
- This code is located in a different workbook than the workbooks being processed.

```vb
Sub ImportCarData()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Copy Car Data to Home"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    ' Open destination.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Destination\Home.xlsx")

    Dim swb As Workbook, sws As Worksheet, srg As Range
    Dim dws As Worksheet, dfCell As Range, i As Long

    For i = 1 To 5
        ' Source
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Source\Car" & i & ".xlsx")
        Set sws = swb.Worksheets(1)
        Set srg = sws.Range("E4:E124")
        ' Destination
        Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(i + 1)
        Set dfCell = dws.Range("A1")
        ' Copy.
        srg.Copy dfCell
        ' Close source.
        swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next i
    
    ' Close destination.
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Runb-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
         & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```